# Django creating Comment System with Ajax

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I want to create a comment system for my page. The system should work without refreshing page.I am very new at Ajax and I probably missing somethings but I don't know what. When I click "comment" button, the page shows something like;

[image]

my codes:

**view.py**

```
def post_detail(request, pk, ):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = request.POST['name']
        content = request.POST['content']
        comment = Comment()
        comment.name = name
        comment.content= content
        return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(comment), safe=False)
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='name')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='comment')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**comment.html**

```
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<hr>
<form method="POST" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 20px" id="comment_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Yorum Ekle" style="margin-left: 20px">
</form>
```

**post_detail.html**

```
...     
    <div id="comment">
    <h2>Yorum Ekle:</h2>
    {% include 'blog/comment.html' %}
    <hr>
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <h4>{{ comment.name }} |
            <small>{{ comment.created_date|timesince }} önce</small>
        </h4>
        <p>{{ comment.content|linebreaks }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<hr>
<hr>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#comment|form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = "/post/12";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: $("#comment_form").serializeArray(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('SUCCESS');

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**forms.py**
`

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'name',
            'content',

        ]
```

What are my mistakes and how can I fix it? Please help me. Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: You haven't told us what is actually wrong, so how can we diagnose the problem? What output do you expect and what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @Jode I posted an answer, but if that is not the only issue you have we'll need more info regarding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with your selector syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#comment|form").submit(function (e) {
        ...
```

`$("#comment|form")` should instead be `$("#comment_form")` in your post_detail.html file.